# Standard says, we can define static data member template like class template and function template, but how exactly?

Tags: c++, templates, static, datamember

The chapter of Templates in the C++03 Standard starts with the following:

> A *template* defines a family of classes or functions.

```
template-declaration:  
     exportopt template < template-parameter-list > declaration
template-parameter-list:
     template-parameter
     template-parameter-list , template-parameter
```

> The *declaration* in a *template-declaration* shall
>
> — declare or define a function or a class, or
>
> — define a member function, a member class **or a static data member** of a class template or of a class nested within a class template, or
>
> — define a member template of a class or class template.
>
> A *template-declaration* is a *declaration*. A *template-declaration* is also a definition if its *declaration* defines a function, a class, or a static data member.

So from what I understand reading the **bold** text is that we can define *static data-member-template* , in addition to *class -template* and *function-template*. But I've never seen *static data-member-template*. How exactly is it defined?  I tried the following, but GCC is not accepting it ([ideone](http://www.ideone.com/MGWm2)):

```
template<typename T> struct X{};

template<typename T>
struct A
{
   template<typename U> static X<U> data_member;
};
```

So I started doubting myself if I understood the quotation correctly. What exactly am I missing? Or how exactly can we define static data member template? What does the bold text mean?

Comment: This does not *define* a static data member, it merely *declares* one.

Comment: Oops.. I got downvote for asking question, and clarifying my doubts. :|

Comment: Not from me, don't know where this comes from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it refers to:

```
template<typename T> int A<T>::staticDataMember;
//                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ declaration
```

If `A` is a class template like the following

```
template<typename T>
struct A { static int staticDataMember; };
```

Comment: Ahhh.. this seems to be correct. Johannes, Awesome as always :D... +1.

Comment: I love the clang underlining :)

Comment: Correct, because in Nawaz’ code no static data member is defined.

Comment: Can you give me a complete working example? It will be helpful for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

You never gave the `data_member` an actual type.

```
template<typename T> struct X{};

template<typename T>
struct A
{
   static X<T> data_member;
};
```

Comment: But that declaration is not of the form of  `template < template-parameter-list > declaration` as the quotation says.